# HTML5 Drag and Drop of nodes

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

With Mozilla I can drag and drop DOM node elements thanks to
the `application/x-moz-node` type.
Is there a similar type with Chrome, Opera, and so on?

Thanks.

Comment: What I've found so far is that it's basically impossible. If you're dragging things on one page, however, you can keep a global object of data and read/write that - there is always only one drag happening at a time, anyway. There seems to be no way to drag nodes between different domains, but as far as I know you can't transfer any special data to another domain by any means. The `postMessage` API also only allows strings (or at least, anything that's stringifiable). Dragging nodes across same-domain iframes is not very pretty but it is possible (the iframe can read the parent global object).

Comment: There don't seem to be any. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291590/what-is-the-data-type-in-html-5-if-i-need-to-drag-and-drop-a-div-to-another-div

Answer (score 1):

If you want consistent behavior of drag-and-drop across browsers, I would recommend that you use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/). With [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/), they've done all the hard work for you.

Comment: This would be the easy solution of course, but it doesn't integrate with the native drag and drop functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Modernizr.draganddrop to detect the capability of HTML 5 native Drag & Drop.

If the browsers support this feature. can use draggable=true to set the node to be draggable. Otherwise, need to use JQuerUI to support it.

Comment: But how would one get the dragged node in the `drop` event? The question is how to set nodes as drag data. Modernizr doesn't add any support, and jQuery UI has little to do with this subject.