# What is the data type in HTML 5 if i need to drag and drop a div to another div?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

in the JS function below, the data type is set as "text"  but this doesn't work because i'm looking at dragging and dropping a div. Is there any way around this? or a data type ?

`function drag(ev) { ev.dataTransfer.setData('Text', ev.target.id);
}`

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla [recommend `application/x-moz-node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types#Dragging_Nodes) for dragging nodes within the document, though that is obviously only going to work in Gecko based browsers.  It's easier and generally more compatible to set a reference to the element as text, like you're doing already, and then use the reference to grab the element in the `drop` event and move it in code to the correct location.